# Why is the number of Haemophilus spp isolates greater than the number of patients in this research?

Tags: research, bacteria, microbiology

"**Whole genome sequencing-based classifcation of human-related Haemophilus species and detection of antimicrobial resistance genes**":

https://doi.org/10.1186/s13073-022-01017-x (open access)

.

.

> "In total, 262 clinical Haemophilus [spp.] isolates were collected
> from 250 patients in three Northern German hospitals"

The only reasonable answer i could think of is that the patients which contributed to more than one isolate, had bacterial infections in several body sites and these infections were thought to be non endogenous.

I think it does not say exactly the specimen origin of each isolate, but it does generally:

> These included blood, eye smears, wound smears, and tracheostomal
> samples, as well as upper respiratory tract (pharyngeal suction/smear,
> nose smear, and tonsillar smear) and lower respiratory tract specimens
> (sputum, tracheobronchial aspirates, bronchial secretion, and
> bronchoalveolar lavage)

Answer (score 2):

The paper doesn't specify, but it does say (in the methods section):

> The samples were taken from routine diagnostics...
>
> The reason for the collection of the samples was based on the diagnostic workflow of the respective physicians with regard to the individual clinical symptoms and additional laboratory parameters of the patients.

This means that in some cases, because of the workflow, more than one sample was taken from at least some patients, and in some cases these additional samples also yielded an isolate that fit the characteristics of a *Haemophilus* species.

The authors also don't specify if those additional samples were taken from different locations on the same patient or were repeated samples from the same location, as sometimes happens when no clinical improvement is seen.